# Como configurar o JBoss AS 7.1 com Demoiselle 2.4.1 para operar com transações distribuídas?

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss, demoiselle

Olá

Meu cenário: aplicação JSF/Demoiselle que invoca um método de EJB, ambos hospedados em um servidor JBoss AS 7.1.1. Durante operações de insert e update em uma página CRUD, a aplicação Demoiselle tem que salvar seus dados em seu próprio DataSource e também salvar alguns outros dados em outroa aplicação por meio da chamada de métodos de EJB, que usará outro DataSource. O dois DataSources estão configurados para **usar JTA** (JTA checkbox marcado na configuração do JBoss).

Apenas em casos de **update**, a tentativa de savar dados lança uma exceção. As últimas partes do stack de exceção seguem:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@14729cfa[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@6a370d1a connection handles=0 lastUse=1467805740289 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@7a5d9cca pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@31c571ea[pool=CartaoDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@11061a5f[connectionListener=14729cfa connectionManager=4b45c7aa warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:147)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
... 175 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@14729cfa[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@6a370d1a connection handles=0 lastUse=1467805740289 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@7a5d9cca pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@31c571ea[pool=CartaoDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@11061a5f[connectionListener=14729cfa connectionManager=4b45c7aa warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:604)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:467)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
... 178 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:474)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:599)
... 180 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: IJ000356: Failed to enlist: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a0a0546:2fd05d09:577134fa:61c7a status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionListener.java:552)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:282)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:467)
... 181 more
```

Quando eu desabilito JTA no DataSource do EJB o problema some.

O que está errado com as minhas configurações?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.4.1/html/transacao.html#d0e892), a configuração é feita com os seguintes passos:

- Adicione no arquivo `pom.xml` a dependência à extensão `demoiselle-jta` :

  `<dependency>
      <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
      <artifactId>demoiselle-jta</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>`
- Informar no arquivo `persistence.xml` o endereço da conexão JTA gerenciada. No caso específico de JBoss e Hibernate, fica assim:

  - Transaction type: `<persistence-unit name="bookmark-ds" transaction-type="JTA">`
  - Datasource JTA: `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>`
  - Configurar a propriedade: `<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />`

Mais detalhes no link acima.